# I accidentally remove my /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/*

Tags: python

I accidentally remove my

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/*
```

with the command

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/*
```

and now I had some broken applications .

How to fix them?

Comment: You find out what packages the applications use and reinstall them. In the future, use Python virtual environments.

Comment: I had tried it , but I didn't know how to reinstall the pkg_resources in arch

Comment: and if I want to reinstall it , it will show "could not get file information for usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/<python package name>"

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like a circular problem. So you tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-pkg-resources`?

Comment: sorry I forgot telling you that I use archlinux

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with archlinux. Would `sudo pacman -S python3-pkg-resources` work?

Comment: No , pacman can't install it

Comment: Oh I love you guys I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found how to fix it.

My Python packages are manage by Yaourt so I did this:

```
$ yaourt -Qs | grep python- | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | cut -d '/' -f 2 > ~/pythonpackage

arr=($(cat ~/pythonpackage))
for i in ${arr[@]};do
    yaourt -Rddsn $i
done
```

and then

```
arr=($(cat ~/pythonpackage))
for i in ${arr[@]};do
    yaourt -S $i
done
```

I am not sure if this is a correct answer, but my broken applications work again now.

Comment: Shouldn't `yaourt -S` suffice to just reinstall the package?

Comment: @choder to get list of installed python packages you should better use this:  
  
```pacman -Qq | grep python-``` (repo)
  
or
  
```yay -Qq | grep python-``` (repo + AUR).
  
`-q` option in pacman is made specifically for this - list only package names. Also to install packages without confirmation there is `--noconfirm` option. So ```pacman -S --noconfirm <pkgname>```.